# codenameone:Is Self Signed Certificate work for IOS?

Tags: codenameone

I've generated a self signed certificate using keytool.My Android application is not Working with self signed cerficate.It gives some exception.

**CertPathValidatorException : Trust anchor for certificate path not found**

I am getting this error when trying to connect to https url using self signed certificate.

- How to get it working on Android
- Will IOS also support self signed certificate for testing purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have such support which is strongly discouraged in newer mobile OS's.

Use regular HTTP instead of HTTPS for development which should work. For iOS you might need this too http://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Comment: Which certificate should i generate for it and How to generate it? Explain me in detail Stepwise.

Comment: Anything that works in the device browser. Signing authorities is a bit out of scope to explain and unrelated to Codename One

Comment: What should I Write(Give me sample code) for  https connection Request and certificate integration in codenameone?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Codename One. It's a server certificate issue, if your server certificate is valid devices will work with it